# Counter and running total / sum in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, cumulative-sum

I have a table in Google Cloud BigQuery with two columns: first column is a date and the second column is boolean. I sort it according to date. Now I simply want to add two more columns: 
1. one that simply counts the number of rows before each row: 1,2,3,...
2. one that counts the number of rows with TRUE value before each row (running sum of True).
How do I do it in SQL?
The following shows all the columns to explain what I mean:

[image]

Comment: are you looking for solution in BigQuery or mySql?

Comment: BigQuery mainly, but I thought maybe a solution with one can be modified to the other one.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant removed the conflicting tags, later the appropriate one can be added back.

Comment: @user2725109 pls share what you have tried so far and where you got stuck with it.

Comment: @shadow - from my experience when I see such combination of conflicting tags (sql, mysql, bigquery) it is in 99.9% cases means just bigquery :o)

Comment: @user2725109 - it is recommended to show what you actually tried and also provide example of input data and expected output - all in text - not images

Comment: Agree, user could provide more info and do a little homework before posting the question  - but it is definitely clear and specific! Also, it DOES NOT make any sense to me to see that such question is put on hold for the reason above and especially AFTER answer was provided and accepted. Just nonsense!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant you probably should not have answered without the OP demonstrating any efforts.

Comment: still, reasoning for `on hold` is quite questionable!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '2018-01-01' dt, TRUE value UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-01-07', FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-01-09', TRUE UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-02-02', TRUE UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-02-19', FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-03-02', FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-03-09', FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-04-28', TRUE
)
SELECT *,
  COUNT(1) OVER(ORDER BY dt) count_previous_all,
  COUNTIF(value) OVER(ORDER BY dt) count_previous_true
FROM `project.dataset.table`
ORDER BY dt
```

with result as

```
Row dt          value   count_previous_all  count_previous_true  
1   2018-01-01  true    1                   1    
2   2018-01-07  false   2                   1    
3   2018-01-09  true    3                   2    
4   2018-02-02  true    4                   3    
5   2018-02-19  false   5                   3    
6   2018-03-02  false   6                   3    
7   2018-03-09  false   7                   3    
8   2018-04-28  true    8                   4
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks!